# Which way is the more computationally efficient for running WRF-Chem with one way nesting: (a) by setting feedback to '0' or (b) using ndown.exe?

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, wrf, wrf-chem

I want to run WRF-Chem with one-way nesting because of the limitations of my system (a linux server with 378 GB of RAM and 32 processors). I have gone through the WRF user guide, which explained how to do one-way nesting using 'ndown.exe'. Also, I found the following lines on the webpage (WRF Namelist.input Best Prac):

"When feedback is off , it is equivalent to a one-way nested run, since nest results are not reflected in the parent domain."

So, my question is: Are both processes equally efficient as far as computational cost is concerned? Or is using "ndown.exe" faster than setting "feedback" to "0"? Which way is better for one-way nesting?
Can anyone please guide me in this regard? That will be greatly appreciated.
Thanking you.
With regards,
Ankan